# Missing particle after など in article about new technologies to monitor employees

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-など

I'm reading this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011528251000/k10011528251000.html) about new technologies that are getting introduced to monitor employees.

I am unsure about the following sentence. I do not understand why there isn't a particle or something like it between the など and the 230. Is this a typo or what is intended here?

> ソフトウェアをつくっている会社**など２３０**の会社が新しい技術を紹介しています
>
> My Translation: 230 companies are introducing new technologies, where these companies and similar places are producing software

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In [*Nominal apposition in Japanese*](https://www.questia.com/library/journal/1G1-132534929/nominal-apposition-in-japanese) (2004), Rumiko Sode calls this など an "exemplifier", and considers this construction a type of apposition in which one noun phrase restates a subset of another.

Basically, you've got two noun phrases next to each other:

> N<sub>1</sub>などN<sub>2</sub>

Which expresses that N<sub>1</sub> is included within N<sub>2</sub>.  In other words, N<sub>1</sub> is a restatement of *part of* N<sub>2</sub>.  It could be translated in various ways depending on context.  For example:

> 秋田犬など大型犬に最近人気がある。
>   Recently, Akitas and other large-breed dogs are becoming popular.

Here, 大型犬 includes 秋田犬 as a subset or an example, and the noun phrases are linked together by など.  Nothing is missing between them.

Likewise, in your example:

> ソフトウェアをつくっている会社など２３０の会社が新しい技術を紹介しています。

The larger set is ２３０の会社, and ソフトウェアをつくっている会社 is some subset of those 230 companies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I did not know など has this function!

Answer (score 4):

> 「ソフトウェアをつくっている会社{かいしゃ}**など２３０**の会社が新{あたら}しい技術{ぎじゅつ}を紹介{しょうかい}しています。」

Conclusion first.  There is nothing missing between 「など」 and 「２３０の会社」.
That is simply perfect grammar in formal speech.

If one ***had to*** insert a particle in between that made sense, that particle would be 「の」.  It would, however, be slightly wordy because there will be another 「の」 coming soon in 「２３０の会社」.  It would also make the sentence sound unnecessarily informal as well.

「A など B」 indicates that A is an example of B.

That is why your translation is slightly off.  Not all of the 230 participating companies are software houses.  There are other types of companies present as well even though the sentence does not mention what kinds of companies they are.  So, the math here is:

The number of software houses + X = 230

X is the number of other types of companies participating.

Comment: `It would also make the sentence sound unnecessarily informal as well.`  How so?  I'm not super up to date on my formality, but I'm not seeing how it would be less formal.  Would you mind explaining?